# What to send trough sockets (cross language)

Tags: python, .net, xml, sockets

I have a project at work, where i have to use a server-client environment, my daemon i would like to write in Python connected to a local MySQL database and should handle all the requests of the clients, the clients would be also python for serial barcode reading, en sending to the daemon, but also a management application in .net that could execute commands and/or request data from the daemon.

Now, i managed to send text to and from the clients to the server, (very cool btw) but what is the best practice to send commands, recieving data (fetched from mysql) etc...?

I see alot arround XML / SOAP etc..., is that the best/correct way to send data?

how does other applications this? like an exchange server for example? (just curious :))

Many Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cross language communication I would consider zeromq instead of plain sockets. Also, I would use it in conjunction with bson or Protocol Buffers cause they outperform XML.

If you don't want to switch to zeromq, you still can use bson or protocol buffers imho.

Comment: Good advice for the zeromq, seems cool...

i will check out bson and protocol buffers, i suppose these are the only legit options...

Answer (score 0):

A couple simple solutions for you:

**HTTP** version 1.0 or 1.1 for simple, synchronous client-driven requests; version 2 for kickass complex stuff; WebSocket for ad-hoc asynchronous messages. There's a ton of libraries available, you can easily wrap it into SSL later. It's awesome.

**Delimited JSON** a stream JSON documents can easily be delimited with a byte illegal in given encoding. I'd recomment UTF-8, and thus `\xff` delimiter. JSON is unversally readable and writeable, and you can get by without any extra libraries.